# Allocating memory for array of structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc, calloc

I've a struct like the one who follows:

```
typedef struct author
{
char letter;
char *name[200];
int counter;
} Aut, *i_aut;
```

It consists of a char, and array of "Strings" and int. My goal is to allocate space in memory for an array of 30 of this kind of structs, therefore I tried something like the following:

```
i_aut lista_autores=calloc(30,sizeof(Aut));
```

However, it always returns "segmentation fault". I tried to initialize one at a time too, but with the same result. My question is, how do I allocate memory of this kind and how can I access it later?

Thank you in advance, and sorry for any typo.

Comment: With `char *name[200];` you can have 200 distinct strings in each struct (like you described, an array of strings). But: You´ll need to reserve the strings too. If you want only one string with max. length 200, remove the `*`.

Comment: how are you accessing `name` ?

Comment: When does "segmentation fault" happen? Does it happen when you do only `i_aut lista_autores=calloc(30,sizeof(Aut)); free(lista_autores);` and nothing else in between?

Comment: I have a feeling you want `char name[200]` instead, as an author has but one name (of length at most 199)?

Answer (score 0):

the struct member `name` is an array of 200 pointers.
You may want to assign the result of `malloc` to elements of the array.

```
struct author *i_aut;
i_aut = malloc(sizeof *i_aut);
if (i_aut) {
    for (size_t k = 0; k < 200; k++) {
        i_aut->name[k] = malloc(30);
        if (!i_aut->name[k]) /* error */;
        /* DONT FORGET TO FREE EACH NAME LATER ON */
    }
    free(i_aut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
    struct author **i_aut;
    i_aut=(struct author **)malloc(30*sizeof(struct author*));
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        i_aut[i]=(struct *)malloc(sizeof(struct author));
```

after this you need not allocate space for name[] seperately.
you have array of 30 elements of type struct author* 
and you can access all three type using
        i_aut[i]->letter;
        i_aut[i]->name[j];
        i_aut[i]->counter;
 here i<30